# Equivalence of the definitions of a differentiable map

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-topology

> $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is called differentiable if all the partial differentials exist.

I have a confusion about the definition of a differentiable function $\phi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$.
The definition on my book is as follows:

> $\phi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ is called differentiable if any pullback $f\circ\phi$ is differentiable for any differentiable $f$ defined on the range of $\phi$? (Here, I stick for $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}^m$)

The problem is that nothing is told about the domain of $f$. Are the following definitions equivalent or do they imply each other in any way?:

> Def-1: $f$ above has a domain $\phi(U)$.
>
> Def-2: $f$ above has a domain $W\supset \phi(U)$ for any open $W$.
>
> Def-3: $f$ above has a domain $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What is a "partial differential" of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{|f(p+hx_i)-f(p)|}{h}$ where $p$ is a point at which we evaluate the differentiable, and $x_i$ is the unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $i\in \{1,2\}$.

Comment: @uniquesolution I guess this definition becomes very-super-ugly if I replace $\mathbb{R}^2$ with an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: It is unclear what you are askjng. What are the assumptions on $f$? It cannot be an arbitrary function. I guess it should be a differentiable function and therefore be defined on some open set containing $f(U)$.

Comment: By the way, your book gives a very unusual definition of a differentiable function. Which book is it?

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm sorry. I fixed it. The assumption on $f$  is that it must be differentiable, but there are no assumption on the openness of its domain.

Comment: I agree; this definition classifies as "differentiable" many of the examples given in more standard texts of non-differentiable functions! In particular, existence of partials is *not* the key to differentiability --- approximability via a linear transformation is! Partials are computationally very useful, but they're not the essence of differentiability.

Comment: @PaulFrost My book actually requires for the domain to be open, but I don't want it xD

Comment: What is the *definition* of the partial differentials of a function $f : V \to \mathbb R$ if $V$ is not open?

Comment: $\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{|f(p+hx_i)-f(p)|}{h}$ is the partial differentiable of $f$ at a point $p$ with the direction $x_i$.

Comment: I know, but take for example $V  = \mathbb R \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb R^2$. What happens for direction $x_2$?

Comment: According to my definition, the partial differential does not exist at the direction $x_2$.

Comment: So **no** function $f : V \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable in this case. What would be the effect if we have $\phi : U \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $\phi(U) = V$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Any $\phi$ will be differentiable even if it is not continuous. This convinces me that my artificial definition has no use in this generality. Thank you. You could repeat the argument very briefly in an answer so that I could accept it and close the question.